# HTTP 404 Error in Eclipse Project 2

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to learn how to run a Spring MVC project on a server, and I'm getting an http 404 error.. I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1, Tomcat 8
I can't see errors.

[image]

[image]

The Controller Class

```
    package com.spring.controller;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class OffersController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String showHome() {
            return "home";
        }
    }
```

The JSP

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-        8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Hi there!
    </body>
    </html>
```

Ther Servlet

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         ://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


        <context:component-scan base-package="com.maurice.controllers">
        </context:component-scan>
        <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

        <bean id="jspViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

Web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="2.5">

     <display-name>Own2</display-name>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>offers</display-name>
        <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
        <servlet-        class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: i see that the package of the controller is (com.spring.controller) however you are scanning another package (base-package="com.maurice.controllers")!!!

Comment: ups i changed the package name for this upload and forgot this,

Comment: but this isn't the source of the error

Comment: then what is the name of spring configuration file ? it should be WEB-INF/offers-servlet.xml

Comment: It is WEB-INF/offers-servlet.xml

Comment: I edited the screenshot

Comment: Are you sure that you have this <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.controller"> instead of this <context:component-scan base-package="com.maurice.controllers"> now ?

Comment: Yes I am sure:  <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.controller">